How to get survey and gtsummary to report ALL levels of factor variable
The 3rd level is not appearing in the table. I would like all 4 factor levels of v1.fac to appear, including "Green". Similar to missing = 'always'  is there a way? My almost complete table is below. And the desired table is below that.
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,4,4,4,4,2,4,1,1,1,2,2,2,4,2,1,2,1,4),
                 v2 = c(3,2,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,1,3,3,2,1,3,2,2,1,2),
                 agecat = c(1,3,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,NA),
                 str = c(1,4,1,2,3,6,5,1,4,6,3,4,5,6,1,5,3,2,1,4),
                 wgts = c(1.28,1.77,1.28,1.40,1.44,1.71,1.04,1.28,1.77,1.71,1.44,1.77,1.04,1.71,1.28,1.04,1.44,1.40,1.28,1.77))
df <- df %>% mutate(v1.fac = factor(v1, levels = c(1,2,3,4), labels = c('Red','Blue','Green','Black')),
                    v2.fac = factor(v2, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c('Small','Medium','Large')),
                    agecat.fac = factor(agecat, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c('<18','18-54','54+')))
tabl <- svydesign(id = ~1, strata = ~str, weights = ~wgts, data = df) %>%
      tbl_strata(strata = c('v1.fac'), .combine_with = c('tbl_merge'), .tbl_fun = ~ .x %>%
          tbl_svysummary(include='agecat.fac', by='v2.fac', missing='no', label=agecat.fac~'Age', statistic=agecat.fac~'{n}') %>%
              modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ '{level}') %>%
              modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ NA))
tabl


Getting this:


But I want this instead with the added Green category (I've photoshopped to get this example):


You have missing = 'no' in tbl_svysummary function, did you want missing = 'always' instead?

@Ben Thanks for your idea. I tried that already and results in only displaying the "Unknown" row for the Age variable when it is missing. Instead, I want the "Green" category of v1.fac displayed, despite it not having any observations. Basically a category placeholder displayed. I've edited the post to show my desired output.
